# SQL PHP Query UPDATE does not work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Currently I am trying to update the values in a column with a unique value. I use the following Query:

```
SET @a = 1; UPDATE table_name SET column_name = @a:=@a+1;
```

This query works when using it in phpMyAdmin. But I want to use this query in a php-script. My script is below, but when this is executed the column is not updated. I do not receive an error, so I do not have an indication of what is going wrong.

```
$sql = "SET @a = 1 UPDATE table_name SET column_name = @a:=@a+1";
$result = $link->query($sql);
```

Does anyone have a clue on how to solve this?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Split it in two queries.

Comment: In order to execute 2 queries you have to use [`mysqli::multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Comment: Note: If you want to start from `1` you should initialize `SET @a = 0;`.

Comment: Thanks life-savers,

That works for me!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to add a unique id to your table.

Are you are aware of auto_increment? If you give this to column_name it will automatically number the rows in increasing sequential order in the same manner you are trying to achieve with your current query.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp